# sum MySQL column with spaces in name

Tags: mysql, sum

How do I just simply sum a column in my MySQL database? I thought:

```
SELECT sum(Disbursement Amount) FROM payments
```

but this doesn't work. Says I have a syntax error near 'Amount)

I just need to know how to SUM ONE column of data and I can take it from there

I've searched for a couple days and have found nothing of use to me. I'm also brand spanking new to MySQL so I'm sure that's why ;)

Comment: a column name with a space inside is a bit  -  suboptimal. But quote it with backticks, `sum(\`Disbursement Amount\`)`. If the column is named `Disbursement` then shift the `Amount` behind the closing parenthesis: `sum(Disbursement) as Amount`

Comment: Yes I was thinking the same after the fact, this is just a test database I'm developing to start learning the little quirks of MySQL. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a space in your column name (`Disbursement Amount`), then you need to use backticks to enclose the column name:

```
SELECT sum(`Disbursement Amount`)  as Total
FROM payments;
```

My suggestion would be to not use spaces in your tables and column names.  If you want to have a separator between the two words, you can use an underscore:

```
SELECT sum(Disbursement_Amount)  as Total
FROM payments;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I appreciate it. My query runs now with your suggestion, however, the SUM amount is completely wrong. I'm getting a sum of 612 but 2,775 + 2,775 + 2,775 + 606 is not 612. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your table structure and sample data?

Comment: I apologize bluefeet, but I'm extremely new to MySQL and am not sure how to export those yet. The above are the only values in my column though

Comment: @EricJ If you run `select Disbursement Amount from payments` what do you get as a result?  You only get 4 rows?   Are you running this exact query?

Comment: @bluefeet His column is `VARCHAR` and the values have commas: `2,775` ... So `2+2+2+606 = 612`

Comment: ypercube is correct, it appears to only be summing the first digits. I removed the commas and all is good. THANK YOU SO MUCH EVERYONE!!!

Comment: @EricJ You should be storing numbers as an numeric datatype. Don't store them as a string.